# Passing data to WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly

I'm trying to pass a value from JavaScript to WASM, but it's not working. Here's my C code:

```
extern int x;
int foo() {
  return x;
}
```

In JavaScript, I instantiate the module and set x equal to 5:

```
var importObj = {
  env: { 
    memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({initial: 256, maximum: 256}),     
    _x: 5
  }
};    

WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('test.wasm'), importObj)
.then(result =>
    console.log('Output: ' + result.instance.exports._foo())
);
```

This doesn't produce any errors, but the logged message is `Output: 0` instead of `Output: 5`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you use to compile your C code to wasm? I tried to get this to work on https://webassembly.studio and found that the function `foo` loads the value from memory location `0`. So I was able to produce `Output: 5` by initializing the instances memory from JS:

```
WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch('test.wasm'), importObj)
  .then(result => {
    const mem = new Uint32Array(result.instance.exports.memory.buffer)
    mem[0] = 5
    console.log('Output: ' + result.instance.exports._foo())
  });
```

To be honest I expected the `extern int x` to become an imported global in wasm that can be passed via `importObj`. I hope this still helps to get on the right path.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I use Emscripten for compiling C to wasm.

Answer (score 1):

The current lld implementation doesn't support undefined data symbols at link time.  If you pass `--allow-undefined` you will end up with undefined symbols who's address is 0.

We have been discussing adding support for importing data symbols: https://github.com/WebAssembly/tool-conventions/issues/48